# Правильный парсинг значения Href с внутренней ссылкой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вообще, парсинг ссылки выглядит как-то так (по заверению интернетов):

```
/<a [^<>]*href=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^<>]*>(((?!/si
```

Но в моём случае выдаёт ошибку: *Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing )* 
Искал иные способы, но все идут с ошибками или не ищут ссылку. В моём случае ссылка представляется в виде(кавычки могут быть иные или не быть вовсе, page,id - абстракция):

```
<a href="/page?id=123">подробнее</a>
```

Так как правильно парсить?

Comment: @sinneren, вы регулярку разобрать не пробовали? Она обрезана посередине, там не разбирается закрывающий тег, нету содержимого.  
Парсить html лучше без регулярок, т.к. регулярки предполагают одноуровневый разбор, и это вечно ведет к расстройствам. Без расстройств документ сначала надо поделить на теги, потом с каждым разбираться.

Comment: html я паршу через Simple HTML Dom parser. Но он тоже в свою очередь даёт html, или я не разобрался как с полученными объектами дальше парсить,но выходит, что только через регулярки. Через что еще возможно даже не представляю.

Comment: Ладно, решил через stripos и substr.

Comment: в статье http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html пишут, что парсить все просто и регулярки не нужны.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно использовать DOM.

[Вот пример](http://ideone.com/8AR7iC):

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadXML('<html><body><a href="/page?id=123">подробнее</a><a href="mailto:name@domain.com"><span><b>somename@domain.com</b></span></a><a href="http://domain.com">domain.com</a></body></html>');

$list = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
$link_array = array();
foreach($list as $link){
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    array_push($link_array, $href);
}
print_r($link_array);
```

А вот результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /page?id=123
    [1] => mailto:name@domain.com
    [2] => http://domain.com
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с regexp (JS)

```
var a = '<a href="/page?id=123">подробнее</a>';    
alert(a.split(/(href=\")*"/g)[1]);
```

только это для конкретного случая. Нечётные елементы будут показывать значения href. Переписать на php, думаю, не сложно. P.S. href  может быть не только у А тега (часто ещё meta).