# Как с помощью регулярки достать почту из ссылки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть ссылка на отправку почты  `<a href="mailto:mail@mail.ru">mail@mail.ru</a>`.

Как с помощью регулярных выражений из этой ссылки получить адрес почты? Только есть один нюанс, длина и домены почт в ссылке могут быть разные.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Извлечение содержимого атрибута href](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521670/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-href)

Comment: а вот это более правильное решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426170/178576

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KAqRt3/1 - если прям нужно email вытащить

Comment: Да, действенно! Но я вот так `/\<.*?\>/` удалил всё содержимое ссылки и остался только текст (сама почта) вот что вышло regex101.com/r/w4vpU2/1  заменил на знак пробела это все и осталась почта

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще чем я думал, пару часов изысканий и вот она, регулярочка: `/\<.*?\>/`

https://regex101.com/r/w4vpU2/1